# make curl get the final url and use it for another function

Tags: php, curl

I have URL with variables like this example : http:// remotesite.com/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=149274&tid=372536&channel=0

this URL redirect to http://remotesite.com/static/popups/xxxxxxxxxxx.html

xxxxxxxxxxx is the variables from the 1st link, event_id=149274, tid=372536, channel=0

then xxxxxxxxxxx = 1492743725360 and the link will be :

http://remotesite.com/static/popups/1492743725360.html

how to get this link automatically in php from the link http:// remotesite.com/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=149274&tid=372536&channel=0

then i will use the curl function to get the source code of 1492743725360.html

using :

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http:// remotesite.com/static/popups/1492743725360.html";

    //Get the html of url
    function get_data($url) 
    { 
       $ch = curl_init();
       $timeout = 5;
       //$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.";
       $userAgent = "IE 7 – Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;

    }

    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the html response?

Comment: html response of what?

Comment: of `$html`, if I'm not mistaken, you're trying to scrape a link?

Comment: I'm confused a little bit. You show cURL related get_data() function but actually use file_get_contents();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://remotesite.com/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=149274&tid=372536&channel=0';
$parsed = parse_url( $url );
parse_str( $parsed['query'], $data );
echo $newurl = 'http://remotesite.com/static/popups/'.
               $data['event_id'].$data['tid'].$data['channel'].
               '.html';
```

Outputs:

```
http://remotesite.com/static/popups/1492743725360.html
```

Comment: @ andery if i want to use the $newurl in new function as get page content curl function i will write $url = $newurl in the new function right??

Comment: Just call $html = file_get_contents($newurl); or call $html = get_data($newurl);

Answer (score 0):

Use the function called parse_url(); the first argument is the entire URL. That will return an array with the URL parsed, the part you need is the arguments that are located on the the array key 'query'. IE:

`$parsedURL = parse_url($URL);`

Then, you use the parse_str() function passing the array key 'query' as first value and as a second value where the results will be stored. IE:

`parse_str($parsedURL['query'], $result);`

Then, printing $result will give you:

```
Array
(
     [option] => com_lsh
     [view] => lsh
     [event_id] => 149274
     [tid] => 372536
     [channel] => 0
)
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php